# Problem with Dragging and Ref Retrieval in React-Beautiful-DND

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to create a draggable form similar to Google Forms using react-beautiful-dnd. I've developed an "AreaControl" that moves to the offsetTop of the area when an item is clicked or when the drag ends. However, I've encountered a problem—I don't know how to obtain the ref of the dragged item when the drag ends. As a result, this function is not present in my app. Is there any solution for this issue?

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigilant-borg-2rh6sf?file=%2Findex.js%3A71%2C31&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800063j6kot2n486y%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800023j6kmrecdvgn%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800033j6kkh0645j9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800053j6kat4xdvm9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqokyne800023j6kmrecdvgn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800013j6ktci2de5n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A71%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A31%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A71%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A31%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800023j6kmrecdvgn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800013j6ktci2de5n%2522%257D%252C%2522clqokyne800053j6kat4xdvm9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800043j6k638fwwhk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800053j6kat4xdvm9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800043j6k638fwwhk%2522%257D%252C%2522clqokyne800033j6kkh0645j9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqokyne800033j6kkh0645j9%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)